# Deploying react apps to custom domain name (Ubuntu)

Tags: reactjs, networking, dns

My react app is installed on a ubuntu server. I want to add a custom domain to it. When I pointed the domain to the server. It points to xx.xx.xx.xx but the react app is installed on xx.xx.xx.xx:3000

How can I install the react app on xx:xx:xx:xx:80 ?

Answer (score 0):

Does your app still works with `example.com:3000`? I believe it should.

Your web server's port needs to be on 80 to serve with `http://example.com/` or `http://xx.xx.xx.xx/`. Either change the port to 80, or use a web server such as Nginx to proxy 80 to your 3000.

Answer (score 0):

`React App` doesn't run in `port 80`. So we need to redirect requests hitting `port 80` to `port 3000`.

For this, You need `Nginx` server which helps you with this.

Follow these Steps and Your react app will work on Port 80.

Link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-react-application-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-20-04